# Flex/ActionScript reference?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, documentation

I'm a Java/C++ developer and now I am starting with *AS 3.0* and I want some online reference of the classes and functions that AS has... The site I'm looking for, should be pretty similar to [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference). Or at least allow me to browse the classes that Flex/As has and let me see a little description of what is it good for, with an example on how to use.

I really don't know if such a site exists, or if the community has other kind of documentation system that is broadly used (that will be pretty much welcome too).

Thanks nice people from Stack Overflow, even if this is my first question, I always found what I needed in this great Q&A service.

I've looked in the adobe documentation, but what they have is so static (PDFs mostly). Also should consider that I'm not using Flash/Flex Builder but Eclipse/AXDT so any IDE specific reference wouldn't as helpful as just a reference to the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this Adobe documentation? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html It seems to me, that it fills your needs. You can list all classes and packages, filter by different products (flash/flex/air/...) and by version. For every class, you can see all own properties and methods, plus show inherited methods, etc. It pretty much meets my requirements for language reference/documentation.

Comment: You answered 5 seconds before me so I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Ok, feel a little dumb now. I was there but didn't realize it was a documentation page... Thanks for pointing me back.

Comment: Also check out the flex 4 cookbook plenty of full free versions online :)

Comment: And do yourself the biggest favour ever for any C Java or Flex based developer read this:

http://gskinner.com/talks/quick/#1

use left and right keyboard arrow to navigate.

Performance Coding And Optimisation for Devs. Invaluable.

Comment: Best example of something every flex dev should know:
http://gskinner.com/talks/quick/#53